# Require individual's property values to be a superset of another's?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege

I have defined an ontology with the following classes, properties, and individuals with object property assertions:

```
Class: Employee > Individuals: { EmployeeA }
Class: Skill > Individuals: { Skill1, Skill2, Skill3 }
Class: Job > Individuals: { DBA }
```

```
hasSkill > Domain (Employee) and Range (Skill)
isAskillBy > Domain (Skill) and Range (Employee) <inverse of hasSkill>
requireSkill > Domain (Job) and Range (Skill)
isAskillrequiredBy > Domain (Skill) and Range (Job) <inverse of requireSkill>
```

```
Individual: EmployeeA, object property assertion: hasSkill Skill1 
                                                  hasSkill Skill2
                     , types : hasSkill only ({Skill1,Skill2}) <to close OWA
                     , Negative object property assertion: hasSkill Skill3

Individual: DBA, object property assertion: requireSkill Skill1 
                                             requireSkill Skill2
                                             requireSkill Skill3

       , types : requireSkill only ({Skill1,Skill2, Skill3}) <to close OWA
```

To classify whether an Employee is qualified for a job (in this case, the DBA position), I created the class **Fit** and made it equivalent to:

```
Employee and (hasSkill only (isAskillrequiredBy value DBA))
```

When I run a reasoner in Protege, the reasoner classifies **EmployeeA** under the class **Fit**, but with the closure axioms to address the Open World Assumption (OWA), **EmployeeA** should not be classified as **Fit**, since he does not have all three skills needed for the DBA position.

Comment: You have an individual named JobA with property assertions, but DBA is declared and used in the definition of Fit. Is that an error in the question, or does that match the ontology? In that case, this would explain the problem.

Comment: @Ignazio Thank you for notifying me, I have edited the post. It was a type in the question but I had DBA in my ontology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, recall what the "universal" quantification in OWL means.  The class expression

p only C

is the individuals x such that *if* x is related to y by property p, *then* y must be a C.  That is, p(x,y) implies C(y).  Your query is returning the correct results, but the query doesn't mean exactly what you want it to mean.  The query

> Employee and (hasSkill only (isAskillrequiredBy value DBA))

says that something must be an Employee, and *if* the employee has a skill, *then* the skill must be one that is required by the DBA position. EmployeeA certainly meets that definition, since the skills that EmployeeA has are Skill1 and Skill2, both of which are required for the DBA position.

The problem in this query is the **only**.  It will manifest in two different ways: (i) if someone is qualified for DBA position (i.e., has all the necessary skills), but has additional skills, then you won't retrieve them, since they *have* skills that *aren't* required for the DBA position (but maybe you don't want overqualified people); and (ii) it retrieves people all of whose skills are required for the DBA position, but doesn't require that the people actually have *all* the skills needed for the DBA position.

What you actually want to ask for is individuals that have all the skills necessary for the DBA position.  What you'd need to check is whether an individual *lacks* any skills that are required for the DBA.  The skills required for the DBA position can be found with:

(**inverse** requiresSkill) **value** DBA

The skills not needed for the DBA are simply the negation of that:

**not** ((**inverse** requiresSkill) **value** DBA)

What you'd like to say is that any skills that an individual *doesn't* have must be from that class.  Currently, you don't have a property that connects an individual to the skills that they *don't* have.  If you did, then you could define your "Fit" class as

Employee **and** (lacksSkill **only** (**not** ((**inverse** requiresSkill) **value** DBA)))

Now, the question is whether you can define a property **lacksSkill** that's true exactly when an employee *doesn't* have a skill.  I'm not sure whether you can do exactly that, but you can define

lacksSkill **disjointProperty** hasSkill

which will mean that if **hasSkill(x,y)** is true, then **lacksSkill(x,y)** must be false.  It's not exactly the the same as a negation, because they can both be *false* at the same time, but they can't both be true.

That's enough to make this query work, **and** it removes the need for some of the closure axioms.  You'll still need to close what the position requires, but you don't need to close the skills of the employees.  That is, you don't need to say, e.g., that EmployeeA has *only* the skills Skill1, Skill2.  I created an ontology in Protege that you can use to see this in action.  It has an **EmployeeA** who has Skill1 and Skill2 (not enough to qualify for the job), and an **EmployeeB** who has all three skills, which is enough to qualify.

[image: screenshot]

```
@prefix :      <http://example.org/> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix example: <http://example.org/> .

example:Skill  a  owl:Class .

example:Position  a  owl:Class .

example:Skill3  a  owl:NamedIndividual , example:Skill .

example:hasSkill  a               owl:ObjectProperty ;
        owl:propertyDisjointWith  example:lacksSkill .

example:requiresSkill
        a       owl:ObjectProperty .

example:  a     owl:Ontology .

example:DBA  a                 owl:NamedIndividual , example:Position ;
        a                      [ a                  owl:Restriction ;
                                 owl:allValuesFrom  [ a          owl:Class ;
                                                      owl:oneOf  ( example:Skill3 example:Skill2 example:Skill1 )
                                                    ] ;
                                 owl:onProperty     example:requiresSkill
                               ] ;
        example:requiresSkill  example:Skill1 , example:Skill2 , example:Skill3 .

example:Skill2  a  owl:NamedIndividual , example:Skill .

example:Employee  a  owl:Class .

example:EmployeeA  a      owl:NamedIndividual , example:Employee ;
        example:hasSkill  example:Skill1 , example:Skill2 .

example:Skill1  a  owl:NamedIndividual , example:Skill .

example:lacksSkill  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

example:EmployeeB  a      owl:NamedIndividual , example:Employee ;
        example:hasSkill  example:Skill1 , example:Skill2 , example:Skill3 .
```